# How can I enable wake abilities of a USB device in Windows 10 Professional?

Tags: windows-10, usb, bluetooth, wake-up

I think the title says enough.

I already read through the Internet and tried different things but I can't find this specific topic solved anywhere.

Trying powercfg -deviceenablewake results always in insufficient permission though I ran it as administrator or even system user.

In particular I want my USB Bluetooth dongle to be able to wake my computer from sleep state.

I made sure that my USB ports are powered in sleep state. For example my 2.4GHz Logitech USB dongle (keyboard) can  wake my computer.

Edit:
I'm not looking for wake on lan. The thing is I'm setting up a gaming pc which is hooked to my TV. So I'm just using a Xbox One Gamepad.

I hope someone can help me finally solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

From Hardware management (Run: devmgmt.msc) you can view the devices properties. 
If the Tab for Power management isn't there or doesn't list "**Allow this device to wake the computer**" then it probably doesn't have the ability to do so.

The permission error is likely meaning it can't set that property at all.

If you're doing this from another computer/phone/tablet then explore **Wake On LAN** (WoL). Enable in BIOS and grab an App for WoL.
That is best for waking a computer remotely which then gives you all the normal functions.

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm aware of WoL and it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In a CMD window ran as Administrator get the list of potential wake devices with

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_from_any
```

find your device and enable waking with

```
powercfg -deviceenablewake "Device Name"
```

with the name from the list. [(via)](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/63148-allow-prevent-devices-wake-computer-windows-10-a.html)